# time difference between events in two different tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a paid_activity and free_activity table:

paid_activity model:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk | number | hash(activity_date, user_id, product_id) |
| date | date | date of the activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product associated with the activity |

free_activity model:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk | number | hash(activity_date, user_id, product_id) |
| date | date | date of the activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product associated with the activity |

I need to produce a dormancy table with the model:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk | number | hash(activity_date, user_id, product_id) |
| date | date | date of the spend activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product associated with the activity |
| paid_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity |
| paid_product_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity with the same product |
| free_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity |
| free_product_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity with the same product |

The dormancy table should have a 1:1 row correspondence to the paid_activity table.

I started by making an intermediate paid_dormancy table without the free_ fields:

| Field | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pk | number | hash(activity_date, user_id, product_id) |
| date | date | date of the spend activity |
| uid | number | user who generated the activity |
| pid | number | product the user spent on |
| paid_dormancy | int | days since the user's last paid activity |
| paid_product_dormancy | int | days since the user's last free activity with the same product |

Code:

```
select
    pk
    , date
    , uid
    , pid
    , date - lag(date) ignore nulls over(
        partition by uid
        order by date) paid_dormancy
    , date - lag(date) ignore nulls over(
        partition by uid, pid
        order by date) paid_product_dormancy
from paid_activity
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to merge in free_activity to build the dormancy table.

I cobbled together the following query which doesn't produce the correct results at all:

```
with dormancy_union as (
    select
        ppk pk
        , date
        , uid
        , pid
        , paid_dormancy
        , paid_product_dormancy
        , iff(ppk is null, null,
            date - lag(date) ignore nulls over(
                partition by uid
                order by fpk, date
            )) free_dormancy
        , iff(ppk is null, null,
            date - lag(date) ignore nulls over(
                partition by uid, pid
                order by fpk, date
            )) free_product_dormancy
    from (
        select pk ppk, null fpk, * from paid_dormancy
        union all
        select null ppk, pk fpk, *, null, null from free_activity
)
select * 
from dormancy_union
where pk is not null
order by date;
```

Answer (score 1):

So with some example data:

```
with paid_activity(pk, date, uid, pid) as (
    select 
        hash(column1, column2, column3), 
        to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
        column2, 
        column3
    from values
    ('2023-02-14', 1, 10),
    ('2023-02-01', 1, 11),
    ('2023-01-13', 1, 10)
), free_activity(pk, date, uid, pid) as (
    select 
        hash(column1, column2, column3), 
        to_date(column1, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
        column2, 
        column3
    from values
    ('2023-02-15', 1, 10),
    ('2023-02-11', 1, 10),
    ('2023-01-20', 1, 10),
    ('2023-01-01', 1, 10)
)
```

we can build the priors for the free products by do a date join, and then keep the "most recent" per input rows..

```
), with_priors as (
    select z.*
        ,fp.date as fp_date
    from (
        select p.*
            ,f.date as f_date
        from paid_activity as p
        left join free_activity as f 
            on f.date <= p.date 
            and p.uid = f.uid
        qualify row_number() over (partition by p.date, p.uid, p.pid order by f.date desc) = 1
    ) as z
    left join free_activity as fp 
        on fp.date <= z.date 
        and fp.uid = z.uid 
        and fp.pid = z.pid
    qualify row_number() over (partition by z.date, z.uid, z.pid order by fp.date desc) = 1
)
select 
    p.*
    ,lag(p.date)ignore nulls over(partition by p.uid order by p.date) as l_p_act
    ,lag(p.date)ignore nulls over(partition by p.uid, p.pid order by p.date) as l_pp_act
    ,datediff('days', lag(p.date)ignore nulls over(partition by p.uid order by p.date), p.date) as paid_dormancy
    ,datediff('days', lag(p.date)ignore nulls over(partition by p.uid, p.pid order by p.date), p.date) as paid_product_dormancy
    ,datediff('days', p.f_date, p.date) as free_dormancy
    ,datediff('days', p.fp_date, p.date) as free_product_dormancy
from with_priors as p
order by 2,3,4;
```

| PK | DATE | UID | PID | F_DATE | FP_DATE | L_P_ACT | L_PP_ACT | PAID_DORMANCY | PAID_PRODUCT_DORMANCY | FREE_DORMANCY | FREE_PRODUCT_DORMANCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9,052,164,364,143,044,634 | 2023-01-13 | 1 | 10 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-01 |  |  |  |  | 12 | 12 |
| 3,292,356,339,691,413,099 | 2023-02-01 | 1 | 11 | 2023-01-20 |  | 2023-01-13 |  | 19 |  | 12 |  |
| -3,195,136,054,197,415,933 | 2023-02-14 | 1 | 10 | 2023-02-11 | 2023-02-11 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-01-13 | 13 | 32 | 3 | 3 |

so that last block can be cleaner:

```
select 
    p.pk, p.date, p.uid, p.pid
    ,datediff('days', lag(p.date)ignore nulls over(partition by p.uid order by p.date), p.date) as paid_dormancy
    ,datediff('days', lag(p.date)ignore nulls over(partition by p.uid, p.pid order by p.date), p.date) as paid_product_dormancy
    ,datediff('days', p.f_date, p.date) as free_dormancy
    ,datediff('days', p.fp_date, p.date) as free_product_dormancy
from with_priors as p
order by 2,3,4;
```

giving:

| PK | DATE | UID | PID | PAID_DORMANCY | PAID_PRODUCT_DORMANCY | FREE_DORMANCY | FREE_PRODUCT_DORMANCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9,052,164,364,143,044,634 | 2023-01-13 | 1 | 10 |  |  | 12 | 12 |
| 3,292,356,339,691,413,099 | 2023-02-01 | 1 | 11 | 19 |  | 12 |  |
| -3,195,136,054,197,415,933 | 2023-02-14 | 1 | 10 | 13 | 32 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver! You also answered my previous question (which is related to the same work)! I can't thank you enough. For some reason, I can never wrap my head around SQL.